# Magento 1: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, join-table

I am getting the Error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'status' in where clause
>   is ambiguous

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, CONCAT(soa.firstname,' ', soa.lastname,'', soa.street,'', soa.city,'', soa.region,'', soa.postcode)  AS `full_address`, CONCAT(soas.firstname,' ', soas.lastname,'', soas.street,'', soas.city,'', soas.region,'', soas.postcode) AS `full_address_ship`, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ') AS `skus`, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS `names`, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.product_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS `proid`, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.product_type SEPARATOR ' ') AS `product_type`, `order`.`total_qty_ordered`, `order`.`customer_email` AS `emailbuyer` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `soa` ON soa.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soa.address_type = 'billing'
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `soas` ON soas.parent_id=main_table.entity_id and soas.address_type ='shipping'
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `sales/order_item` ON `sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id WHERE (status = 'processing') GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id` ORDER BY main_table.created_at DESC LIMIT 20
```

Why can't it find the status column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have used more than one table so you have to use `table`.`status` instead of only `status`.